# Blender nodes not compositing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm making quick little scene for a friend and I have been following a YT video (youtube.com/watch?v=uFwdpPkenc4).
The guy is using Blender v2.5 and I'm using 2.78a. I've done essentially the same thing as him but my render layer nodes won't composite at the end. I do have my render set to composite along with having both my render view and composite nodes hooked up at the end.

[image: Full Node Tree]

[image: End Render Result, Why is this happening?]

Comment: I would suggest using only one Viewer node and connecting all the test results you'd like to preview to it with Ctrl+Shift+Left click (if using Node Wrangler addon). For now it renders in the end result which is at the point of the first Viewer node. Hard to tell why, as I've tested different Viewer nodes don't interact with that but going with only one would easen the task.

Comment: Disable Alpha in the Composite Node

Comment: What does the viewer node at the end of the tree look like? (right now you are looking at the first viewer node, seeing only the vector blur.) I expect your problem is in the add node. use an alpha over node there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think in terms of layers, this layer will be your background:

[image]

All other images will be composited on top so it doesn't need any transparency or alpha channel. Do not mask it and let the background be flat and uncut.

[image]

Over your background you are using a foreground layer. Use **Alpha Over** instead of Add.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much cegaton, that fixed my problem, I'm still new to 'advanced' blender. I'm just getting into node for this little project.